# Create instance of a Class type using newInstance()

Tags: scala, reflection

So I'm trying to create an instance of a class using following statements (simplified):

```
class A
classOf[A].newInstance()
```

The call throws:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: A$A426$A$A426$A
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: A$A426$A$A426$A.<init>()
```

I did try defining *init()* method with different variations with no success. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

---

Related, didn't work for me:

[No such method exception Hadoop <init>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446635/no-such-method-exception-hadoop-init)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30183564/432903)

Comment: Class A has a constructor without arguments?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui I can't say for internal implementation but statement `new A` is valid

Comment: Where are you declaring A?

Comment: Typing in those two exact lines works in the Scala REPL (v2.11.7). Show us your *real* code that has this problem, instead of this simplified example. The error means that the class has no no-args constructor. An `init()` method is not a constructor, so adding an `init()` method will not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for suggestion about inner class but actually it has to do with IntelliJ IDEA 'scala worksheet' -- scala sandbox file with interactive evaluation. For some reason, instantiation described above throws only in a worksheet, it does work in a regular Scala REPL.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11301699)

Comment: I am the author. The actual answer "why it doesn't work" is unknown, because it's IDE defect/feature.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is that A is being declared inside anther class. See this example:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class StackoverflowSpec extends Specification {

  class B

  "A" should {
    "be instantiatable" in {
      classOf[A].newInstance() must not(beNull)
    }
  }

  "B" should {
    "throw an instantiation exception" in {
      classOf[B].newInstance must throwAn[InstantiationException]
    }
  }
}

class A
```

I think that what's happening is that in the jvm, your classes are `A` and `StackoverflowSpec$B`, and that `StackoverflowSpec$B` requires a `StackoverflowSpec` to be passed in to it's constructor, because it's an inner class.